# Does a mutex lock prevent access until it's unlocked?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Assume this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;  
int a = 0;

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp) 
{ 
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
   a = 5;
   while (1) sleep(1);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
   return NULL; 
} 

int main() 
{
   pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
   pthread_t thread_id; 
   pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
   while (1){
    a = 6;
    sleep(1); 
    printf("%d\n", a);
   }       
   pthread_join(thread_id, NULL); 
}
```

The first output is `5` but the subsequent prints are all `6`. How is that?
`myThreadFun` creates a lock and goes in an infinite loop and never unlocks, so how can `main` overwrite `a`?

Whatever put between a `lock` will be protected? i.e if I have more variables to protect in `myThreadFun` I just put the between the same lock?

Does a lock block access until it's unlocked, or it block access only until its own read/write is done? i.e to prevent a partial read and write?

Comment: The lock prevents execution of code.  your loop in `main` doesn't bother with the lock and just does whatever it wants.  Add the lock to your main loop and see what happens.

Comment: but `a` is locked in another thread, how can It do what it wants? whats the point of locking it then?

Comment: Locking only prevents other locked critical sections sharing the same lock from executing. Since `main` is not locked, it's free to do whatever it wants. By the way, the fact that `5` prints first is entirely accidental, so "the first output is `5`" is only applicable to some random schedule you got on a particular run, not in general. There is a race condition on the resource `a`.

Comment: The variables `a` and `lock` are not connected.  There are programming languages in which it would be possible to declare that nobody can write to `a` unless they first hold `lock`.  C is not one of those languages.

Comment: This is an unconditional, infinite loop: `while (1) sleep(1);` So, the next line that you put after it, `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);` will never be executed. There's no point in putting any lines of code after a statement that will never finish executing.

Comment: When we say "`a` is locked", we mean that some thread holds a mutex that no thread will access `a` without holding. Since another thread can access `a` without holding the mutex, the mutex does *not* lock `a`. You did *not* lock `a`, you locked a mutex that doesn't do anything because there is nothing that it locks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `myThreadFun` creates a lock and goes in an infinite loop and never unlocks

True, but what is that lock used for? Nothing. Nobody else is honoring the lock except the thread. The `main` program accesses the variable without requesting any lock. The program does not know anything about the fact that the lock is supposed to guard the `a` variable. It could be used for anything really. A lock only prevents critical regions of code from being executed by multiple threads at the same time given that all of them are locking at the beginning of the critical region and unlocking at the end.

If you want this to behave correctly, you'll have to use the lock properly, and lock/release it for every part of code which interacts with the variable. Something like this (in `main`):

```
while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    a = 6;
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

> Does a lock block access until it's unlocked, or it block access only until its own read/write is done? i.e to prevent a partial read and write?

A lock doesn't know anything about read/write, code or variables. A lock is simply an object that has two states: either locked or unlocked. If its state is unlocked, then it can be locked. If its state is locked, then it cannot be locked until an unlock occurs (and requesting a lock causes the thread to wait until the lock gets unlocked).

> This still prints 6. I want it to print 5. I want to lock `a` in a thread so no other thread can touch it.

This is a different issue. What you need to do here is to ensure that the thread you are starting gets access to the `a` variable *before the main thread*. If you want to achieve this result, you'll need to synchronize the two. In other words, you want the `main` program to wait until the thread holds the lock on the variable.

This can be achieved in different ways. Here's a working example using a semaphore (take a look at [`man sem_overview`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for more information). **NOTE** that while it might seem like the following could be achieved using another mutex instead of a semaphore, this is not the case. The main difference between a mutex and a semaphore is that a mutex can only be unlocked by the same thread that locked it, while a semaphore can freely be locked or unlocked by different threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sem_main;
pthread_mutex_t lock_var_a;
int a = 0;

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_var_a);

    // Signal main that I acquired the lock.
    sem_post(&sem_main);

    a = 5;
    while (1) {
        printf("Thread: a = %d\n", a);
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_var_a);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    sem_init(&sem_main, 0, 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock_var_a, NULL);

    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);

    // Wait for thread to acquire the lock.
    sem_wait(&sem_main);

    while (1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_var_a);

        // This code will never be executed.
        a = 6;
        printf("Main: a = %d\n", a);
        sleep(1);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_var_a);
    }

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
}
```

In the above example program `main` will wait for the thread to acquire the lock before continuing. The resulting output will be:

```
Thread: a = 5
Thread: a = 5
Thread: a = 5
...
```

Comment: This still prints 6. I want it to print 5. I want to lock `a` in a thread so no other thread can touch it.

Comment: See my comment above--you have a race condition on `a`, and with Marco's post here, a race condition on `lock`. It's nondeterministic which thread will set its value first. If you want to ensure ordering, why even bother using a thread here? The example is too contrived to show your actual use case.

Comment: @Josh you should have specified that in your question. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: The OP hasn't understand that the mutex **lock instruction execution not variable access**. He expect to protect access to variable `a`. Isn't so! The execution is locked, the variable is still freely accessible.

Comment: @Frankie_C That's right, I thought it locks variable access.

Comment: Is lock used in a shared function, or used before calling a shared function?

Comment: @Josh that question doesn't make much sense, it entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Josh There is no way, in any language I know at least, to lock access to a variable. To obtain such behaviour you must restrict access to a single code piece, and protect it with the lock. Then always access the variable from there. In this case you preserve from modification. To do what you want you must use a different software approach.

Comment: why not implement a mutex of your own to lock access to a variable.

Comment: @rsonx implementing "a mutex of your own" is the worst way to go about it and will 100% cause problems. Mutexes/locks/semaphores, atomicity and concurrency in general are very hard to get right. There is no reason to try doing it yourself when there are plenty of standard APIs that already provide this functionality and have been thoroughly developed, optimized and tested for decades.

Comment: @Frankie_C It's not particularly hard to implement a C++ class that wraps any other class such that no operation can be performed on that class without holding a particular mutex, effectively allowing you to lock an instance of that class. There are actually some cases where this is useful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree. I didn't understood that the answer was related to my previous affirmation. Anyway the question is about plain C.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to be accessible *only* to a particular thread, declare it *inside* the thread function:

```
void *myThreadFun(void *unused) 
{ 
   int a = 5;
   while (1) sleep(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Now `main` can't get at it at all, and locking is unnecessary.

Comment: well my point was to understand `locking`. so it's not what I thought it is.